# C - Powers of a^b for big numbers using Array

Tags: c

The question consists of two numbers, a and b, and the answer to it is the sum of digits of a^b.

I have written the below code. It is giving correct result in all cases. But when the input is as such a < b, then after giving the correct answer, I am getting segmentation fault.

I tried a lot to debug it but could not identify the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance..!

```
#include<stdio.h>

void power (int, int, int *product);
int main()
{
    int a,b,product[200];
    scanf("%d %d",&a, &b);
    power(a,b,product);
    return 0;
}

void power(int a, int b, int *product)
{
    int i,m,j,x,temp,sum=0;
    int *p = product;
    *(p+0)=1; //initializes array with only 1 digit, the digit 1
    m=1; // initializes digit counter
    temp=0; //Initializes carry variable to 0.
    for(i=1;i<=b;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
               x = (*(p+j))*a+temp;
               *(p+j)=x%10; 
               temp = x/10; 
            }
             while(temp>0) //while loop that will store the carry value on array.
             { 
               *(p+m)=temp%10;
               temp = temp/10;
               m++; 
             }
    }
    //Printing result
    for(i=m-1;i>=0;i--) 
              sum = sum + *(p+i);
    printf("\n%d",sum);
              printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Just fire it up in the debugger.  X marks the spot.

Comment: But I can't help noticing that `product` is declared as an array of integers and its bound is never passed into `power()`.  Might as well fix that design issue before proceeding, even if it's not the cause of the segfault.

Comment: Side note: you can treat a pointer as if it was an array. So `*(p+0)=1` can be written as `p[0]=1`. And `*(p+j)` is the same as `p[j]`

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below code does what you are trying to do. Which is simple and looks good too.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void power (int, int);
int main()
{
   int a,b;
   scanf("%d %d",&a, &b);
   power(a,b);
   return 0;
}

void power(int a, int b)
{
   int c=1,sum=0;
   while(b>0)
   {   
      c = c*a;
      b--;
   }   
   printf("%d\n",c);
   while(c!=0)
   {   
      sum = sum+(c%10);
      c =c/10;
   }   
   printf("%d\n",sum);

}
```

Comment: Thanks @pala. This code works fine, but I need to write the code that will work for big numbers like 100^1000. So i have used array in the code.

Comment: Thanks @Brian. I am trying to debug the code but I am unable to do so. I am using GDB debugger. I had set breakpoint as 1 and I am keep on pressing next but the code is not ending and not even throwing error.

Comment: @Brian I got this error while debugging => Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040074c in power (a=100, b=1000, product=0x7fffffffdb60) at chesterrevenge3.c:29
29                *(p+m)=temp%10;